# Search solution to an integral

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, integral

When I try to solve a problem of a personal research, I get the following integral:

$$E\left(X\sqrt{(\alpha X)^{2}+4}\right)=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sqrt{(\alpha x)^{2}+4}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\exp\left\{-\dfrac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^{2}\right\}dx$$ on what $X\sim N(\mu,1).$ I tried some substitutions, but I did not succeed! Could someone suggest something to try to solve it?

By using this [page](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) and by replacing $a$ and $\mu$ by fixed numbers, I get accurate numerical results, indicating that the integral converges. I would like the analytical solution, if it exists!.

Comment: Other than the uninteresting cases (where $\alpha=0$ or $\mu=0$), there does not appear to be an analytic solution.  I've tried it using *Mathematica*'s `Integrate` function and Rubi (http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) from within *Mathematica*.

Comment: "accurate numerical results" doesn't mean "there's a closed form expression for the definite integral".

Comment: @Glen_b Yes it's true! I corrected the question!

Comment: Let the integrand be $f(x).$ Numerical integration is very nicely behaved when you compute the integral of $f(x)+f(-x)$ (from $0$ to $\infty$) after using the substitution $x=y^2.$  A saddlepoint approximation should work fairly well for that, too.